# Python - Decimal - можно ли применить ко всем переменным в скрипте?

Tags: python

Всем привет!
Допустим у меня есть список, который состоит из float: `x=[1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4]`.
Некий скрипт, который я создам прогонит этот список через кучу формул; при этом нужно, чтобы округление шло с заданной точностью.
Использование round проблему точного округления не решает, а прописывать каждый рез Decimal(...) как минимум неудобно.
Пробовал изменить тип данных в списке на Decimal через скрипт ниже, но получилась полная ерунда.
Есть ли удобные варианты точного округления без постоянного указания Decimal?
Заранее спасибо!

```
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 3
x=[1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4]
for i in range(len(x)):
    y=Decimal(x[i])
    x[i]=y
```

Comment: А можете уточнить задачу: вам нужно чтобы округления производились при промежуточных вычислениях, то есть, вычисления нужно производить с меньшей точностью, чем обеспечивает тип float?

Comment: Сразу можно сказать, что цикл можно упростить. По идее то же самое делает такое выражение: x = list(map(Decimal, x))

Comment: askh, да, мне нужно чтобы было округление промежуточных результатов. У меня задача состоит в создании скрипта, который воспроизводит расчеты коммерческой программы. А она все результаты вычислений округляет до 7 цифр после запятой